# Connected 1-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading the beginning of the first volume on the introduction to Differential Geometry by Spivak.

In the first part he defines manifolds and states that 'the *only* connected 1-manifolds are the line $\mathbb{R}$ and the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$'.

(1) Is that '*only*' a direct consequence of the definition of manifold? I do not really see the answer. It is also true that, at this point of the book, Spivak uses results from Algebraic topology/Homology (without proving them) to give a wider outlook on the world of manifolds. So it might well be that the answer is not trivial. If it actually is, I would like to see why.

(2) Does this fact imply that the only surfaces of revolution in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which can be obtained by connected 1-manifolds are cylinders and 2-tori?

Comment: It is certainly not a direct implication of the definition, and though it is not too hard to prove, it is not trivial either.

Comment: Can you give an idea or the proof/provide a reference?

Comment: Here is a "proof," which is not really a proof because it sweeps away a few important ingredients. You're trying to classify curves which do not intersect themselves and do not have endpoints. No matter how wild a curve is, you could parametrize it by arc length. If the arc length parameter is injective, it must be a wiggly curve homeomorphic to a line. Since the curve doesn't intersect itself, if it's not injective, it's periodic, and you have something that looks like a wiggly loop, homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: @AlfredYerger thanks for the idea. Can you suggest any book where I can find a formalisation of this?

Comment: Do Carmo's curves and surfaces in its first chapter explains how to parametrize curves by arc length once they are embedded. You need a theorem that says this is always possible. The Whitney theorem is probably overkill, but the easy Whitney theorem shows it can be done in dimension $2(1) + 1 = 3$, which is exactly the case Do Carmo treats in his curves and surfaces book. Easy Whitney appears in Spivak a little later on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The only 1-manifolds are $\mathbb R$ and $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113705/the-only-1-manifolds-are-mathbb-r-and-s1)

Comment: Here's another duplicate with slightly different point of view https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304107/characterization-of-1-dimensional-manifolds?rq=1

Comment: @LeeMosher I have edited my post with a supplementary sub-question.

Comment: It's not super trivial to prove this. In fact, "the line with two origins" and "the long line" are near-misses. They are both locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, but the first fails to be Hausdorff and the second fails to be second countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following resources: [this](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~e_murphy/notes4.pdf) or [this](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779577337825/classif1manifs.pdf)
or ([this](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.966/2014SP/965/class.pdf) (all lecture notes for classes). Or [on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2356795/4280) as well, with bonus link. [This one](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/wdgillam/1manifolds.pdf) looks pretty formal.